Hilbert space question: if $M=\{f\in L^2(0,+\infty)\ |\ \int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^xdx<+\infty\}$, what is $M^\perp$?
This was from a Real Analysis exam:

In the Hilbert space $H=L^2(0,+\infty)$. Consider
$$M=\left\{f\in L^2(0,+\infty)\ \bigg|\ \int_0^\infty f^2(x)e^xdx<+\infty\right\}$$
Find $M^\perp$.

Since the functions $M$ are not very restricted, finding $M^\perp$ turned out to be a challenging task. We know that $$g\in M^\perp \iff \int_0^\infty g(x)\cdot f(x)\ dx=0 \hspace{1cm}\forall\ f\in M $$
For example, since $e^{-ax}$ is in $M$ whenever $a>1$, so a function $g$ in $M^\perp$ should verify at least $\int_0^\infty g(x)\cdot e^{-ax}\ dx=0 $ for every $a>1$. However, I couldn't think of even one such $g$, except from $0$.
Additional informations that may or may not be helpful (previous questions on the same exercise):

$M$ is a vector subspace of $H$

$M$ is not closed


Any suggestion is helpful, thank you.

$M$ is dense in $H$ (because $C^{\infty}_c\subset M\subset H$, and the first is dense in $H$). So the perp must be ${0}$. In fact these statements are equivalent.

Note that for every segment $[a, b] \subset (0, +\infty)$ the indicator function $$I_{[a, b]}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &x \in [a, b] \\ 0, &x \notin [a,b]\end{cases}$$ lies in $M$.
It follows that if $g \in M^\perp$, then $\int_{a}^b g(x) \mathrm{d}x = 0$ for every $b > a > 0$, and thus $g = 0$ in $L^2(0;+\infty)$.

But if $M^\perp$ is only $0$, doesn't this mean that $M$ is the whole space $H$?

No, this is one of the problems with non-closed subspaces. $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is not $M$, it is equal to the closure of $M$.

You are right, thank you

Let $f\perp M.$ Observe that $e^{-x/2}f\in M.$ Thus
$$0=\langle f,e^{-x/2}f\rangle =\|e^{-x/4}f\|^2$$ Hence $e^{-x/4}f(x)=0,$ i.e. $f=0.$
Remark The same reasoning can be applied if $e^{-x}$ is replaced by a function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)>0$ almost everywhere.
